# How to configure RTEMS in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, real-time, rtems

I want to develop a simple program using RTEMS in Eclipse using Ubuntu.
I have installed **RTEMS CDT Support** following https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/Developer/Eclipse/Plugin But I can't configure Window > Preferences > C/C++ > RTEMS paths, because /opt/rtems-4-9 (default value) doesn't exist. 
When I've tried to use RTEMS Toolchain in a new project, next message is shown: 
*'Invoking: RTEMS C++ Compiler
/opt/rtems-4.9/bin/g++ -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -MMD -P -MP -MF"src/HelloWorld.d" -MT"src/HelloWorld.o" -o "src/HelloWorld.o" "../src/HelloWorld.cpp"
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/rtems-4-9/bin/g++: not found
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:20: src/HelloWorld.o] Error 127
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Buil migth be incomplete'*

What am I doing wrong? What can I do?
Please help me.
Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Seems to me the g++ compiler is missing. Is that the case? Maybe it uses a different name.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lof for your message.
What can a I do? Do I have to install something else?
I've look for 'rtems' in all the system, but I found nothing. (sudo find / -name rtems*)
I've tried this https://github.com/RTEMS/rtems-docs/blob/master/eclipse/rtems.rst too, but './boostrap' returns a lot of error messages:
./boostrap: 249:autoreconf:not found
grep: Makefile.in: No such file or directory[..]
Thanks, Anna

Comment: What are you using. If it is ubuntu, try to install the ```build-essential``` package first. You might be missing a bunch of tools...

Comment: Yes, I am using Ubuntu. I've run 'sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install build essential' It didn't install anything, because I've the newest version (12.8ubuntu1) alrayd installed. Thanks

Comment: Where did you download your version of rtems?

Comment: I've install RTEMS in Eclipse > Help > Install New Software > ​ftp://ftp.rtems.org/pub/rtems/eclipse/updates/. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: But what about the path ```/opt/rtems-4.9/bin/```? Normally Eclipse only downloads the extension and uses some installed RTEMS afaik. I think you need to separately download the rtems package and build it yourself. After that you would integrate it with Eclipse.

Comment: I followed these instruccions https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/Developer/Eclipse/Plugin. I didn't know I should do anything else. Where can I read how to install rtems?

Comment: Fro example https://ftp.rtems.org/pub/rtems/releases/4.11/4.11.3/rtems-4.11.3.tar.xz but this is version 4.11. There are older releases on the page. Within the packages there is a README. You most likely will have to build it yourself. After that you can use the eclipse plugin.

Comment: Now I'vet just tried this https://docs.rtems.org/releases/rtems-docs-4.11.3/user/installation/index.html#posix-host-tools-chain. But when I run 'sudo ./source-builder/sb-check' an error message is shown: ' RTEMS Source Builder - CHeck, 5 (78c6e159d467) error: exe: not found: (__bison) /usr/bin/bison error: exe: not found: (__flex) /usr/bin/flex error: exe: not found: (__makeinfo) /usr/bin/makeinfo Enviroment is not correctly set up'

Comment: Well then make sure, you have bison, flex and makeinfo installed. On your ubuntu you might want to install synaptic (nice GUI for apt) and look for these programs.

Comment: Tanks, I will try.

Comment: Hello, In the last step of https://docs.rtems.org/releases/rtems-docs-4.11.3/user/installation/index.html#rtems-tools-and-kernel (../source-builder/sb-set-builder --prefix=/opt/rtems/4.11 4.11/rtems-i386) it shows next error message: 'error: building i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1'

Comment: Can you create a new question for this and put the whole error message there. I can only see one part of it and does not really help me. Just create a new one and link to that. We are happy to help you. :-)

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452913/problem-with-rtems-tools-and-kernel-installation