# Problem with RTEMS Tools and Kernel installation

Tags: c++, eclipse-plugin, rtems

I'm installing RTEMS in Ubuntu 19.10. In the last step of https://docs.rtems.org/releases/rtems-docs-4.11.3/user/installation/index.html#rtems-tools-and-kernel (../source-builder/sb-set-builder --prefix=/opt/rtems/4.11 4.11/rtems-i386) it shows next error message (I've deleted the first part of the report because it 's impossible to post more than 30000 characteres):

```
[..]
../../gcc-4.9.3/gcc/lto-compress.c:28:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include <zlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/rtems/releases/rtems-source-builder-4.11.0/rtems/build/i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1/build/gcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1058: lto-compress.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3975: all-gcc] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:863: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/development/rtems/releases/rtems-source-builder-4.11.0/rtems/build/i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1/build'
shell cmd failed: /bin/sh -ex  /home/user/development/rtems/releases/rtems-source-builder-4.11.0/rtems/build/i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1/doit
error: building i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
```

For more information see: [How to configure RTEMS in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318092/how-to-configure-rtems-in-eclipse)
Thanks,
Ana

Comment: It seems you are missing the zlib development package? Have you installed ```sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev```? After that execute ```./configure``` and try to build it again. You should get further.

Comment: After install zlib1g-dev, I've tried 'sudo ../source-builder/sb-set-builder --prefix=/opt/rtems/4.11 4.11/rtems-i386' but it returns: Build FAILED. log-> [..] make[2]: *** [Makefile:1058: cp/except.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3975: all-gcc] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:863: all] Error 2
shell cmd failed: /bin/sh -ex  /home/user/development/rtems/releases/rtems-source-builder-4.11.0/rtems/build/i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1/doit
error: building i386-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1

Comment: Have you tried to enable the logging for the source builder? Add a "--log=mylogfile.log" to your sb-set-builder command line. Sometimes it helps to have the complete log for analyzing the problem.

Comment: By the way: You are using a 4.11 version of RTEMS. Note that the 4.11 release is now quite some time back. RTEMS currently has only very few releases with long times between them. But the development version is quite stable nearly all of the time. Beneath that the 5.1 release will be out in the next weeks (not sure exactly when) and you might can think about using one of the snapshot release packages.